# Using shared library in Gyp in node-sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, gyp

I'm new to Gyp. Instead of compiling my dependency, I would like to use a shared library, in particular, the libsqlite3.so which is already on my machine. The main binding.gyp currently looks like

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'node_sqlite3',
      'sources': [
        'src/database.cc',
        'src/node_sqlite3.cc',
        'src/statement.cc'
      ],
      'dependencies': [
        'deps/sqlite3/binding.gyp:sqlite3'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How do I change this so that a shared sqlite3 library is used?  The binding.gyp in the deps folder has a section that looks like below. I don't think I need gyp to do any compilation of sqlite3 for me, so switching type to shared_library is probably not the right answer.

```
'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'sqlite3',
      'type': 'static_library',
      'include_dirs': [ '.' ],
      'direct_dependent_settings': {
        'include_dirs': [ '.' ],
        'defines': [
          'SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1',
          'SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3',
          'SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE'
        ],
      },
      'defines': [
        '_REENTRANT=1',
        'SQLITE_THREADSAFE=1',
        'SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3',
        'SQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE'
      ],
      'sources': [ './sqlite3.c', ],
    },

    {
      'target_name': 'shell',
      'type': 'executable',
      'dependencies': [ 'sqlite3' ],
      'sources': [ './shell.c' ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Update.** I was able to get things to compile by changing by binding.gyp to this

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'node_sqlite3',
      'sources': [
        'src/database.cc',
        'src/node_sqlite3.cc',
        'src/statement.cc'
      ],
      'ldflags': [
        '-lsqlite3'
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I go to run a program using the module, I get

> node: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sqlite3/build/Release/node_sqlite3.node:
>   undefined symbol: sqlite3_open_v2

as if the shared library is not loading or is not accessible. I think I'm close. libsqlite3 was installed to /usr/local/lib

> ```
> /usr/local/lib$ ls
> libsqlite3.a   libsqlite3.so    libsqlite3.so.0.8.6  node_modules  python2.7
> libsqlite3.la  libsqlite3.so.0  node                 pkgconfig
> ```

**Update2.** The plot thickens. I tried ldd on the executable created by node-sqlite3

> ```
>     linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffd7168000)
>     libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fc9451df000)
>     libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc944fc2000)
>     libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc944c04000)
>     libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc94490a000)
>     /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc945704000)
>     libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc9446f4000)
> ```

Clearly missing libsqlite3. So perhaps my ldflags statement did not really work as planned.

Answer (score 15):

Here's the answer.

```
{
  'targets': [
    {
      'target_name': 'node_sqlite3',
      'sources': [
        'src/database.cc',
        'src/node_sqlite3.cc',
        'src/statement.cc'
      ],
      'link_settings': {
          'libraries': [
              '-lsqlite3'
          ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Upon use of ldd:

> ~/node-sqlite3/build/Release$ ldd node_sqlite3.node
>           linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe9548000)
>   **>         libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007f6649504000)**
>           libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f66491ff000)
>           libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6648fe1000)
>           libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6648c24000)
>           libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f6648a20000)
>           libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f6648725000)
>           /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f66499cd000)
>           libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f664850f000)

Comment: In my case, I needed to add support for ssl and crypto libraries.  I found the syntax above from tofutim was very helpful except for one thing.  Instead of using '-lsqlite3', I needed to use 'libcrypto.dylib' and 'libssl.dylib'.   There was no dash needed in the library specification.

I am using Yosemite, OSX 10.10 with Xcode version 6.1.1