# Why did most implementations still have cmath functions in global namespace in C++03?

Tags: c++, namespaces

As I understand it, in C++03 `#include <cmath>` must declare the functions only in `namespace std`. Since C++11 they may additionally be declared in global namespace. This is the result of the practice where most C++ implementations declared the functions in global namespace (presumably `#include`ing `<math.h>`), and then just did `using ::acos;` etc. in `namespace std`.

But it seems to me that it would be similarly easy for the implementations to do something like this in their `<cmath>`:

```
namespace __C_LANGUAGE_MATH_H
{
#include <math.h>
}
// ...
namespace std
{
// ...
using __C_LANGUAGE_MATH_H::acos;
// ...
}
```

Why wasn't this practiced instead of just polluting the global namespace? Does my suggested solution have some major drawbacks which made the C++ committee allow pollution of global namespace in C++11?

NOTE: this does work, and linker gives no errors, at least with GCC + Binutils-ld. I've actually tried and edited GCC's `cmath` file like follows, and compiled my project which actively uses `cmath` functions successfully (after fixing some calls which mistakenly didn't specify `std::` in the project):

```
mv /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/cmath{,.bak}
sed -i -e 's@\(# *include <math.h>\)@namespace __C_LANGUAGE_MATH_H\n{\n\1\n}@' \
    -e 's@\(using \+\)::@\1__C_LANGUAGE_MATH_H::@' /usr/include/c++/5.3.0/cmath
```

Comment: Including math.h in a namespace doesn't move the *implementations* of these functions to that namespace, so you get a linker error. In practice, some C++ implementations *had to* use the C library as a base for its functionality (not limited to math). The changes in C++11 just documented current practice.

Comment: Some implementations only defined `extern "C"` versions (non-overloaded) in global namespace, as those would be unusable anyway due to presence of those names in C runtime.

Comment: @BoPersson: Why a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @BoPersson why linker error? If they are `extern "C"`, which they should be, they still have unmangled names, and are only referenced _in user source_ through namespace. For linker they still look like good old unmangled C names. At least it's so for GCC in Linux. I have actually tried to edit GCC's `cmath` file and got good results.

Comment: You mention the behavior was changed in standard. Have you looked at corresponding [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#456)? The problem is this approach is impractical since c++ standard library is built on top of maybe independent c library and was not followed anyway. Say `cstdio` need to provide `EOF`, `BUFSIZE`, `FOPEN_MAX` macros that can only be done reliably by including c library headers.

Comment: @frymode that's not a problem if the headers are included into a separate namespace, as I suggested in my example code.

Comment: @Ruslan You'll still need to deal with say `::FILE` (by including `<stdio.h>`) and `std::FILE` (by including `<cstdio>`) types difference. I also found [issue discussion](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6257) in gcc bugzilla - they tried different approaches but in the just left it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in corresponding issue [discussion](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6257) in gcc bugzilla this approach will not allow including C header after C++ because of include guards:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h> // include skipped by include guards

...
sin(x); // error: no sin in global namespace
```

As you mentioned standard requirements to C library wrappers were changed after issue was posted in [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#456) and previous requirements have been declared impractical from implementation point of view.

Comment: Thanks for the link to bugzilla, it does answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

They don't do it that way because it doesn't work. Try it. There's no function in the C library named `__C_LANGUAGE_MATH::acos`.

Comment: It will work since `acos` declared as `extern "C"` in `math.h` causing it to be linked unmangled.

Comment: @frymode - sure, if the standard C headers all had `extern "C"` everywhere the problem would be easy. But they don't, and C++ library implementors often don't have control over those C headers.

Comment: They should - otherwise c++ mangling would be applied and they won't link.

Comment: Even if they don't we can always include them with `extern "C" { #include <lib.h> }`

Comment: @frymode - no, wrapping `#include` directives in `extern "C"` doesn't work. A source file that did `#include <math.h>` followed by `#include <cmath>` wouldn't get anything in `std` because of the include guards in math.h.

Comment: It has always worked and afaik is the only way to disable mangling for C header - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23626709/4074081.

Comment: I mean the full code for proposed `cmath` would be `namespace __C_LANGUAGE_MATH { extern "C" { #include <math.h> } }`